# PHP files not launched in internal browser of Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu

Eclipse was correctly bringing out the php files in internal browser...but for past one day it just stopped working...When run button was clicked nothing happened...When i started clicking  a lot of times,it opens a dialog box with "performing pre-launch check",which fades away quickly and nothing happens...I've checked Window->Web Browser->Internal Web Browser ..checked with php file's properties -> Run/Debug Settings ..nothing seems to work..any suggestions?

Comment: OMG! its working now...Hmmm..This restart thing is the first step to try in every problem...Anyway it wasnt working in the evening,late evening it worked,then it didnt now its again running..Thnx for ur help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try restarting the system.

That might work